# spring security 5.2 multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with oauth2ResourceServer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have multiple `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`'s in my code, each resides in a different class.
We are migrating to spring-security 5.2, and as a result, we should remove `@EnableResourceServer` and replace it with `oauth2RespourceServer` DSL way.

First `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is called `CommonWebSecurityConfig`, and it includes many ant-matchers that **don't have any shared prefix**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CommonWebSecurityAutoConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


    http
        //  .requestMatchers()
        //  .antMatchers("/* Should I add all (long) list of matchers here?*/")
        //  .and()


            .authorizeRequests()

            .antMatchers(GET, "/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/loggers/**").hasAuthority("scope1")
            .antMatchers("/info/**").hasAuthority("scope2")
            .antMatchers("/metrics/**").hasAuthority("scope3")
            .antMatchers("/configurations/**").hasAuthority("scope4")
            .antMatchers("/odata.svc/**").hasAuthority("scope5")
            .antMatchers("/dataCenters/**").hasAuthority("scope6")
            .antMatchers("/metadata/v1**").hasAuthority("scope7")
            ... 
            ... 
            ... 
            ... 
            ... 
            ... // list goes on
            ...

            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt()
            .jwtAuthenticationConverter(getJwtAuthoritiesConverter());  
}
```

Second WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is `AccountsWebSecurityConfig` meant to be the second to be validated against. I.e. if a request did not match any ant matcher in `CommonWebSecurityConfig`, it should be validated against `AccountsWebSecurityConfig`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.xyz..**.security")
@Order(AFTER_COMMON)
public class AccountsWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            //  .requestMatchers()
            //  .antMatchers("/accounts/**") 
            //  .and()
        
        .authorizeRequests()
            
            .mvcMatchers("/accounts/v1/go").hasAuthority("scope33")
            ... 
            ... // list goes on
            ... 
        .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt()
            .jwtAuthenticationConverter(getJwtAuthoritiesConverter());  
             
            
}
```

My questions:

1. Requests are not being validated against `AccountsWebSecurityConfig`: any request that starts with "accounts" is granted access!
   When I uncomment the 3 lines at the beginning of `configure()` in both classes, it start to work.
   This is a different behavior to what we had prior to spring-security 5.2: we did not have to add requestMatchers to make it work. Is this a new requirement?
2. If yes, then do I have to add requestMatchers to all antMatchers? what if I have so many of them that don't share a prefix, as in `CommonWebSecurityConfig`?
3. Do I have to add `and().oauth2ResourceServer()` to both of them?

Comment: 1. Adding `requestMatchers` is how you specify which requests should be processed by that `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` (in this case `CommonWebSecurityAutoConfiguration`). If you weren't using this before how did you differentiate which request applied to which adapter? 2. Yes, you need to add all matchers that you want `CommonWebSecurityAutoConfiguration` to apply to. 3. What are you trying to accomplish? Do you have different authentication mechanisms for different requests?

Comment: regarding #1, I don't know, it just worked without any request matchers... maybe it's some new requirement (?!)
regarding #3, no, it's the same mechanism. is it enough to add oauth2ResourceServer to CommonWebSecurityConfig, and it will be applies to both?

Comment: You need to add `.oauth2ResourceServer()` to both security configurations if you want it to apply to all requests. If you only add it to `CommonWebSecurityConfig` then it will only apply to the `requestMatchers` specified in `CommonWebSecurityConfig` and not any other endpoints.

Comment: You may find the Multiple HttpSecurity [section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#multiple-httpsecurity) from the Spring Security reference docs helpful.

Comment: If you change the order of the 2 config then you don't need to add .requestMatchers() to the last one, it will process all the requests which were not processed by the configs before it. Do not forget to add .anyRequest().denyAll() or .accepAll() at the end of the matchers to handle all the other paths which are not enumerated there